# I need a regex that would tell me if URL starts with http://i.imgur.com

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So I need a regex that I can use in `preg_replace` that'll tell me if `$string` starts with `http:// (or https) i.imgur.com/`

Any help? I'm not that good with regex heh

so far what I have:

```
<?php
$url = "httPs";
if (preg_match('#^http#i', $url) === 1) {
// Starts with http (case insensitive).
die('ye');
}
else
{die('nop');}
?>
```

Comment: Have you gotten hung up somewhere? Looks like you stopped at the protocol.

Comment: consider using `stripos` instead of a regex

Answer (score 0):

Try /\/\/i\.imgur\.com/

Does that make sense? The double slash after http(s) allows the pattern to only check at the beginning of the domain of the url

So

```
if (preg_match('\/\/i\.imgur\.com', $url)) { ...
```

Comment: Just use a different delimiter than the "\". You're also missing the closing delimiter and this doesn't meet the check for protocols the user is looking to have.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$url = 'https://i.imgur.com/image';
if (preg_match('/^https?\:\/\/i\.imgur\.com\//', $url)) {
    die('yes');
} else {
    die('no');
}
```